# How to use external data in Unit Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I've got lots of unit tests which needs lots of txt, data, html etc. files. Externally storing these files makes life so much easier to update test cases adding new test cases etc.

However having dependencies in Unit Tests brings lots of headache in different systems and in different test runners.

What are the best practices?

1. Externally storing them and
   relatively linking these files in
   the code? (*causing problems in some
   test runners, or requires extra
   configuration*)
2. Embedding all these files in the
   Unit Test dlls and read from there
   (*makes creating tests harder*)
3. Storing in a hardcoded
   location(*obviously causing so many
   problems when you check out the code
   in a different place*)

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: Please number the options.  Bullets are confusing.  What problems are you having in your test runners and what "extra" configuration are you talking about?  Why is option 1 so bad?  Can you provide specific issues?

Comment: It doesn't work with nUnit sometimes, I coulnd't isolate the version or the configuration. But the main problem is when "working directory" changes sometimes it can't find the relative files any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a local folder in my test project and get the test files with code like:

```
public static FileInfo GetTestFileInfo(string fileName)
{
    var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    return new FileInfo(dir + @"\..\..\TestData\" + fileName);
}
```

Oh yes, I'm using MbUnit.

Comment: AFAIK MBUnit support working directory options. I think nUnit is doing something awkward although I just noticed if I leave it with "TestData\xxx.txt" it works. At least for now. I was trying to get current directory.

Answer (score 0):

My practice has been to embed test resources in unit-test assemblies and pull them out using [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx).

NUnit testing is fixture-oriented anyway, so once you have the fixture (*i.e.*, a particular set of resources) set up, adding additional tests is easy.